# Buttons on top on image on different screensizes - Android

Tags: android, image, layout, button

I am creating a xml layout for android in which I have a imageview which shows an image of a human body. On top of this imageview I have placed buttons for arms, legs etc. However my problem is the buttons are misplaced when launching the app on a phone with a larger screen. Is there any solution for creating a layout with buttons on top of the image which works on different screens?

Regards

SOLVED:
I solved the issues by adding my image to a layout for which I assigned a specific range of x y dp instead for aligning the layout with top/bottom which resulting in the layout to stretch when using a larger screen. Then the buttons which I added to the layout would not "change" position and stay correct acoording to the image.

Comment: Please post your layout XML or you'll only get wild guesses.

Comment: put your button after imageview like `<imageview1 > <imageview2 >`....`<imageview3>` `<button1>` `<button2>`...like that

Comment: Hi guys thank for your replys I solved the issues by adding my image to a layout for which I assigned a specific range of x y dp instead for alligning the layout with top/bottom which resulting in the layout to stretch when using a larger screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions in the developer guide?

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You can also find an example application:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I had a go at reading the instrutions again:) I solved the issues by adding my image to a layout for which I assigned a specific range of x y dp instead for aligning the layout with top/bottom which resulting in the layout to stretch when using a larger screen. Then the buttons which I added to the layout would not "change" position.